# C++ ссылки и структуры

Tags: c++

Какой из способов будет лучше в коде, передача структуры в функцию по значению, или же по ссылке? Я понимаю, что иногда нужно использовать только ссылку/указатель, но как быть, например, с просто выводом структуры? или тут уже от личных предпочтений зависит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо работать с исходным передаваемым объектом - то только по ссылке.

Если не надо...

Если копирование - затратная процедура, лучше передавать как константную ссылку. Если что-то мелкое - можно и по значению.

*"По-моему, так". (с) Пух*. Но всегда бывают исключения :)